# Recalling Inventory Transaction Adjustments using Square Connect API

Tags: square-connect

Using the Square Connect API, is there a way to recall the inventory adjustment transactions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to fetch a merchant's inventory adjustment history with the Connect API. I've passed this use case along to the API development team.